# Register signal SIGTERM handler in sub process doesnt work

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

```
import signal
import traceback
from multiprocessing import Process
from time import sleep

class register_signal:
    def __init__(self, job):
        def _(_signo, _stack_frame):
            self.job()
            if self.prev_signal:
                self.prev_signal(_signo, _stack_frame)
        self.job = job
        self.prev_signal = signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, _)
        print("registered terminate signal")


def process():
    register_signal(lambda: print("terminate callback"))
    sleep(10)
    print("done")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            p = Process(target=process)
            p.start()
            sleep(2)
            p.terminate()
            print("terminate called")

        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
    print("Done")
```

The phrase : terminate callback never print, while it should have if signal was working... How to do this right? im running on windows though im looking for a solution for macos as well

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, it worked for me as intended on Linux. One iteration resulted with this output:

```
registered terminate signal
terminate called
terminate callback
...
done
```

I think its not working for you on Windows, because the meaning of `p.terminate()` is different on Windows. From the [multiprocessing documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process.terminate) `p.terminate()` kills the underlying process with `TerminateProcess()` and from my understanding of Windows, [you can't register a handler for `TerminateProcess()` in your program](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040722-00/?p=38373).